# Angular UI Router - state.go after module running

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code (posts.js) :

```
'use strict'

angular.module('myBlog.posts', [
    'myBlog.posts.controllers',
    'myBlog.posts.directives',
    'myBlog.posts.services',
    'myBlog.posts.filters',
    'ui.router'
]).config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function(stateProvider, locationProvider) {
    stateProvider.state('allPosts', {
        url: '/posts',
        templateUrl: 'modules/posts/views/posts.html',
        controller: 'PostController'
    });
    stateProvider.state('singlePost', {
        url: '/posts/:id/:permalink',
        templateUrl: 'modules/posts/views/singlePost.html',
        controller: 'PostDetailsController'
    });
}]);
```

and main code (app.js):

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('myBlog', [
  'myBlog.posts',
  'myBlog.controllers',
  'myBlog.directives',
  'myBlog.filters',
  'myBlog.services'
]).run(['$state', function(state) {
    state.go('allPosts');
}]);
```

I got no errors, but this code didn't work (i.e. after module loading I was not got to the 'posts' state. What's wrong?

Comment: I think you need to describe where "$stateProvider" comes from?  As far as I can tell, it may be "https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router"

Comment: I add this library through script tag, and add this dependency to angular.module as you can see.